# How to assign HTML as a variable value in PHP?

Tags: php, html, variables

My goal is to store some html-formatted data in a variable, then echo it later.

For example:

```
<?php 
$foo = '<div id="x">';
echo $foo;
?>
```

The above doesn't work. Why?

**Edit**

Sorry for the bad question.
I thought it didn't work because nothing is visible when viewed in a browser.
Of course nothing is visible because there is only a div and no text. Doh!
My "real life" version of the above script was broken due to an extra apostrophe.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "doesn't work". What is the intended output and what is the output you are getting? It works fine for me.

Comment: By "Doesn't" work, I mean that nothing shows up on the page when I expect to see some HTML... but, see my above edit.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, the question makes more sense now, and the answers as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably works, but you're not seeing it because it's in the source code and not displayed visually on the web page.

Are you looking to actually display the source code in the web page? If so you will need to turn the `<` and `>` characters into `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see what wouldn't work in your example (unless stackoverflow mangled some of your characters). You're alternating the quotes. On the other hand, you didn't say what doesn't work. Is it a compile error or nothing is printed, or...?

does this work?

```
$foo = "<div id=\"x\">";
```

if there's a fair amount of html text, take a look at [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
$name = 'MyName';

echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

or...

```
$mytext = <<<EOT
... a bunch of html text here ...
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. The error must be somewhere else, check the error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$foo = '<div id="x">something</div>';
echo $foo;
?>
```

works for me. You did not close your div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<?php $chatid ="<div id='chatid'></div>"; 
echo $chatid; 
 ?>
</div>



<script>
function chatuser(id)
{
document.getElementById("chatid").innerHTML= id;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.